# Separator between header and data in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to build a simple JTable which has no gridlines apart from a single horizontal separator between the table header and table data. The separator should span the entire width of the table exactly like a JSeparator. I have managed to achieve the desired appearance using JLabels and a JSeparator placed within a GridBagLayout, however the result is somewhat unwieldy and I can't help but feel that more concise solutions exist (perhaps using a MatteBorder?). Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: The solution can be achieved using the single line of code:

```
table.getTableHeader().setBorder(new MatteBorder(0,0,1,0, Color.BLACK));
```

Comment: *"I have managed..."* - Show us how did you manage.

Comment: `I can't help but feel that more concise solutions exist (perhaps using a matteBorder?).` Sounds reasonable to me. Try placing the Border around the table header and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thats the sort of thing I was thinking, however was not sure how to target just the table header.

Comment: `not sure how to target just the table header.` table.getTableHeader().

Comment: Dear oh dear, how did I not see that before? That also works perfectly! `table.getTableHeader().setBorder(new MatteBorder(0,0,2,0, Color.BLACK));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably did something similar:

1. Create a TableCellRenderer.

   ```
   TableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

       final JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel();
       {
           //setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
           headerLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 3, 0, Color.RED));
           headerLabel.setOpaque(true);
           headerLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
       }

       @Override
       public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
               Object value,
               boolean isSelected,
               boolean hasFocus,
               int row,
               int column) {
           if (row == -1) {
               label.setText(value.toString());
               return headerLabel;
           }
           return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
                     row, column);
       }

   };
   ```
2. Use it for the table header (row == -1). One could also used it for the cells.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); ++i) { 
       table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setHeaderRenderer(renderer);
   }
   ```
3. Either use

   ```
   table.showHorizontalLines(false);
   table.showVerticalLines(false);
   ```
4. or

   ```
   table.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
   ```

I you use only a cell renderer for the header, the following might suffice:

```
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 3, 0, Color.RED));
    renderer.setOpaque(true);
    renderer.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```